# How to evaluate v-if directive only once with Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to evaluate the `v-if` directive only once on an element and ignore any changes in the boolean expression after that? For example:

```
<div v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
     <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
     <span>{{ item.status }}</span>
     <span v-if="match.lastUpdateEpoch">Last Changed {{ getDateFromEpoch(match.lastUpdateEpoch) }}</span>
</div>
```

I only want the third and final span to be displayed if the value is non-zero when the items are initially loaded and rendered but I only want the `v-if` expression to be evaluated once. So, if the value of `match.lastUpdateEpoch` is initially 0, it won't be displayed. But if the value changes to something non-zero at any stage, I still don't want it to be displayed. It should only respect the first evaluation. Is this possible using a directive or something else that doesn't involve me creating additional state variables? I am aware of `v-once` but that only means the value itself will not be re-rendered when it is updated, the show/hide expression will still be evaluated.

The `items` are initially set based on some JSON data returned from my server e.g.

```
var VUE = new Vue({
    el: '#vue-root',    
    data: {
        items: [],
        ...

...
var items = loadItems(); // ajax server call 
VUE.items = items; 
// each item is an object e.g.  
// {name:'a',status:'1',lastUpdateEpoch: 0}
// {name:'b',status:'2',lastUpdateEpoch: 123456789}
```

Comment: "_So, if the value of match.lastUpdateEpoch is initially 0_" how do you set this value initially? Inside the created() or mounted() method?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`v-once`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-once) directive, which renders the element only once. In addition, you'd have to change `v-if` to [`v-show`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-show) to perform the initial rendering (and only rendering).

```html
<span v-show="item.lastUpdateEpoch" v-once>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        { id: 100, name: 'John', status: 'Active', lastUpdateEpoch: 0 },
        { id: 200, name: 'Bob', status: 'Idle', lastUpdateEpoch: new Date() },
        { id: 300, name: 'Charlie', status: 'Idle', lastUpdateEpoch: 0 },
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getDateFromEpoch(epoch) {
      if (!epoch) return ''
      return typeof epoch == 'string' ? epoch : epoch.toDateString()
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.item {
  margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id" class="item">
    <span>{{ item.name }}</span>
    <span>{{ item.status }}</span>
    <span v-show="item.lastUpdateEpoch" v-once>Last Changed {{ getDateFromEpoch(item.lastUpdateEpoch) }}</span>
    <div>
      <input v-model="item.lastUpdateEpoch" type="date">
    </div>
  </div>
  <pre>{{ items }}</pre>
</div>
```